# What is the difference between scale-free network and small-world network?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, graph-theory, network

What is the difference between [scale-free network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-free_network) and [small-world network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_network)?

I can't understand from the definitions around the web if they are both the same name for one thing. Do both follow a power-law distribution of the nodes degree?

In particular is it true that scale-free networks are a subset of small-world networks?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not seem directly relevant to physics

Comment: This question seems closable since a straightforward Google search would immediately provide the answer, cf. e.g. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/9/2451) and [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/121/2451) meta post.


Comment: @akhmeteli lots of physicists study scalefree and/or small-worlds networks.  Have a read through PRE or PRL.

Comment: @Joel: With all due respect, I am not sure I have to "read through PRE or PRL" to decide if a question should be closed. If the OP does not want his/her question to be closed, it's (s)he who should care about that. The question and the links offered by the OP did not impress me as directly relevant to physics.

Answer (score 1):

They're different, but in many cases they present themselves together.

I don't remember the formal definitions, but a scale-free network should certainly have a power law distribution of nodes degree. And a small-world has to do with a low average average path-length.

Starting from a scale-free network and adding a few randomized links between nodes you obtain a nice small-world network.

Comment: Scale-free = powerlaw distribution of degrees.  Small-worlds = high clustering, but short path lengths.  Adding randomized links in a scale-free network does NOT generate a small-world network.

Comment: Are you thinking about what happens when you randomly rewire a lattice?